# Can I store signed 16bit value in single channel in webgl2?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, webgl, webgl2

Is there a way to store signed 16bit value inside single channel?

Im trying to store it inside red channel like this:

```
  gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R16I, width, height, 0, gl.RED, gl.SHORT, image);
```

but it results in error:

```
[.WebGL-000022F401016900] GL_INVALID_OPERATION: Invalid combination of format, type and internalFormat.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For integral  data the format argument must be `gl.RED_INTEGER`:

<s>`gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R16I, width, height, 0, gl.RED, gl.SHORT, image);`</s>

```js
gl.texImage2D(gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, gl.R16I, width, height, 0, gl.RED_INTEGER, gl.SHORT, image);
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I have a followup question, do you know how can I get this channel in shader? `texture(u_image, v_texCoord).r;` results in `Mismatch between texture format and sampler type (signed/unsigned/float/shadow)`

Comment: @ffsa The sampler type must be `isampler2D`. See [Sampler (GLSL)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Sampler_(GLSL)). In this case `texture(u_image, v_texCoord)`  returns a `ivec4`.